# How to make admin and user login using java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to check employee type in my user profile table and choose when user verification done what would be load for that user.

```
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps,ps2;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelmgt","root","");
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM userprofile WHERE userName = ? AND passWord = ?");
            ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT* FROM userprofile");
            ps.setString(1, jTextField_userName.getText());
            ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(jPasswordField_login.getPassword()));
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                while(rs2.next()){
                    String userType = rs2.getString("emp_Type");
                    if(userType.equals("ADMIN")){
                        this.setVisible(false);
                         Admin_Panel ap = new Admin_Panel();
                         ap.setVisible(true);
                         break;
                    }else if(userType.equals("RCEP")){
                        this.setVisible(false);
                        Admin_Panel ap = new Admin_Panel();
                         ap.setVisible(false);
                        Reception rcep = new Reception();
                        rcep.setVisible(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }else{
                conn.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"UserName Or Password Invalid");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What error you getting ?

Comment: `Admin_Panel` in `else if` section in unnecessary.

Comment: i got 3 columns in my sql table. they are username, password and usertype. so in my code i can validate user and give access to login. i want to check usertype and load different forms as their usertype. that's my problem. sorry for my english xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use to queries for this task? I think you may want something like this.

```
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelmgt","root","");
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM userprofile WHERE userName = ? AND passWord = ?");
        ps.setString(1, jTextField_userName.getText());
        ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(jPasswordField_login.getPassword()));
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
                String userType = rs.getString("emp_Type");
                if (userType.equals("ADMIN")){
                    this.setVisible(false);
                     Admin_Panel ap = new Admin_Panel();
                     ap.setVisible(true);
                     break;
                } else (userType.equals("RCEP")){
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    Admin_Panel ap = new Admin_Panel();
                     ap.setVisible(false);
                    Reception rcep = new Reception();
                    rcep.setVisible(true);
                    break;
                }

        } else{
            conn.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"UserName Or Password Invalid");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```